# When I fill the PDF form using pdf-lib it clears the font property of the field

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, pdf-lib.js

I'm using pdf-lib to fill the PDF form through this code:

```
  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(existingPdfBytes);

  pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);
  const cambriaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fs.readFileSync('./fonts/cambria-font-0346.ttf'));

  const form = pdfDoc.getForm();

  const fieldSecondName = form.getTextField('second_name');
  fieldSecondName.setText('Bradburry');
  fieldSecondName.updateAppearances(cambriaFont);
```

It works well and fills the field with right font, but when I open PDF's form in Acrobat and look at properties of the processed field, the font property is empty, however it was filled before. [You can see it in the attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCOIr.png)

My field has this font set before processing and after this processing it becomes clear.

This is a problem because user can open file and refill this field and it can set default font. But I need it to save my font.

I've been trying to use these methods and properties:

```
form.defaultFontCache.value = cambriaFont;

fieldSecondName.defaultUpdateAppearances(cambriaFont);

form.updateFieldAppearances(cambriaFont);
```

Any tips how to make font property of the PDF's field save its value. Or may be I need to solve it from some other side. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I need to see it in different readers. But I can't get it about transfer.sh. You suggesting me to send my file through this service here so you can check it or something else?

Comment: https://transfer.sh/%28/nSqwC9/input.pdf,/WxnfHo/output.pdf%29.zip

Comment: both of input and output are in last zip

Comment: Thank you sir for help and ideas. Hope to clarify it with support

Comment: Got it, thank you! All these I can do through js and get correct pdf with data and fonts! I need to check it

Comment: Thank you a lot, your tips have helped me, especially about using other libs. I worked it out with this one: https://github.com/phihag/pdfform.js. It really fits in handling pdf forms. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this recently and was able to work around it by setting the acroField value directly. So, instead of doing the following:

```
fieldSecondName.setText('Bradburry');
```

Try doing this:

```
fieldSecondName.acroField.setValue(PDFString.of('Bradburry'));
```

When you've finished filling your text fields you'll also need to manually set 'NeedAppearances' on the acroForm dictionary like so:

```
form.acroForm.dict.set(PDFName.of('NeedAppearances'), PDFBool.True);
```

Using the methods above I was able to (for the needs of my application and PDF's) completely forgo the necessity of loading and embedding a custom font. One other item to note, my solution doesn't call:

```
fieldSecondName.updateAppearances(cambriaFont);
```

I'm not sure if calling that will affect the original font settings of the field (which you want to preserve).